# Replace a number inside of a text file

Tags: python

I have a file.txt

```
some text
another text
text with the number to be replaced bla123
another text
etc
```

I know that the number I'm looking for is on line 3. I also know this is the only number in the line.
For example, here, I want to replace "123" with "3333".
I don't know what the number will be nor it's length before searching for it.

file.txt should look like this:

```
some text
another text
text with the number to be replaced bla3333
another text
etc
```

Comment: Great – what have you tried? Do you know how to open files? Read them line by line? Find strings in lines? Do you know the `str.replace` function? Those are the tools you'd need.

Comment: Is it always the last word on line3?

Comment: is there anything else you know about the number? E.g.: Is it the only number on line 3? Is it the last number on line 3?

Comment: @AKX I am bit stuck here. I do this for finding all occurences of a specific string in a file in another situation.

Comment: '  
with open(filepath, "r") as f:
            file_content = f.readlines()
            file_content = str(file_content)
            result = re.findall("some string", file_content) 
'

Comment: Put that in your question instead of a comment and tell us where you're stuck with it: what it doesn't do that it should do, or what it does that it shouldn't.

Comment: @KawishQayyum no

Comment: @Nik I know it is the only number in the line and the line number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this in 3 easy steps:

1. read the file and keep the lines in memory
2. replace any number on line 3 (mind that arrays are 0-indexed in python) with a replacement string
3. write the output to your file

This uses the regex module re

```
import re

with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

replacement = '3333'
lines[2] = re.sub('\d+', replacement, lines[2])

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use re library to do so

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

re.sub will replace any specific regular expression pattern with whatever you want. If you use '\d+' as your pattern, it'll replace any number with what you want. Since  there is only one number, this should do the trick

So if your line is s_line :

```
import re
number = 3333
new_string = re.sub('\d+', str(number), s_line)
```

So to complete the global exercice, here is what the code should look like :

```
import re
number = 3333

my_file = r"path/to/file"
file_content = []
with open(my_file, 'r') as f_in:
    line_number = 1
    line = f_in.readline()
    while line:
        if line_number == 3:
            line = re.sub('\d+', str(number), line)
        file_content.append(line)
        line_number += 1
        line = f_in.readline()

with open(my_file, 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write("".join(file_content))
```